# Why does database query look like this?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to query the database and show a result. This is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string message)
{
    var Result = from Client in db.Clients
                   where Clients.ClientName == message
                   select Clients.ClientName;

    ViewBag.Message = Result;

    getCurrentUser();
    return View();
}
```

Where message is variable taken from an input element. I want to show it using `ViewBag.Message` in view. On page I see this:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[ClientId] AS [ClientId], [Extent1].[ClientName] AS [ClientName] FROM [dbo].[Clients] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[ClientName] = @p__linq__0
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Result` variable contains a LINQ Query - not a string. Since you imply that you want to show one message, you need to get the first result - not the query itself:

```
ViewBag.Message = Result.FirstOrDefault();
```

This, however, assumes that you actually want the `ViewBag.Message` to be the value of the `ClientName` database column *(which in turn is the same as `message`)*, which I suspect is not what you really want...

To answer your original question:

What you see is the result of calling `ToString()` on a `DbQuery<T>`, which gives you the SQL query used to fetch the data you want.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. And you have right, when I used FirstOrDefault its answering again something strange, but its answering only when I searching existing ClientName in base.

Answer (score 0):

The query will only be executed once you loop through it. So you need to call Result.ToList() to actually get the value

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string message)
    {
        var Result = from Client in db.Clients
                       where Clients.ClientName == message
                       select Clients.ClientName;

        ViewBag.Message = Result.ToList();

        getCurrentUser();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This will print "System.Collections.Generic.List'[Client]".

Comment: You´ll need the first element of that list, not the list itself

Comment: When I taking first element i have something like that:
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Client_02A0BB155C71D9541E0B7869114C4906EB16FF7D51481C04B389528738517799
It means, I have bad sql command?